# glibc pthread_join crash when call pthread_join() twice

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthread-join

I have written the following code using the POSIX pthread library:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg) {
    char *code = "1";
}

int main() {
int res;
pthread_t a_thread;
void *thread_result;

res = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, thread_function, NULL);
if (res != 0) {
    perror("Thread creation failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

sleep(5);
printf("\nWaiting for thread to finish...\n");
res = pthread_join(a_thread, &thread_result);
printf("res[%d]\n",res);
if (res != 0) {
    perror("Thread join failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
res = pthread_join(a_thread, &thread_result);
printf("res[%d]\n",res);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

On executing the code I got the following output:

```
Waiting for thread to finish...
res[0]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In the code, I want to test What happens if you call the pthread_jion() function
twice after the thread is finished. The first call to the function is correct, and the second crash. The backtrace:

```
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  pthread_join (threadid=140150565050112, thread_return=0x7fffa0a2c508) at 
pthread_join.c:47
47    if (INVALID_NOT_TERMINATED_TD_P (pd))
(gdb) bt
Python Exception exceptions.ImportError No module named gdb.frames: 
#0  pthread_join (threadid=140150565050112, thread_return=0x7fffa0a2c508) at 
pthread_join.c:47
#1  0x00000000004008d5 in main ()
```

And I check the pthread_join.c file:

```
39 int
40 pthread_join (threadid, thread_return)
41      pthread_t threadid;
42      void **thread_return;
43 {
44   struct pthread *pd = (struct pthread *) threadid;
45 
46   /* Make sure the descriptor is valid.  */
47   if (INVALID_NOT_TERMINATED_TD_P (pd))
48     /* Not a valid thread handle.  */
49     return ESRCH;
```

In the line 47, the Macro definition checks Whether the pd is a valid thread handle. If not, return ESRCH(3).

However when I run the same code in another Linux environment, I got the following output:

```
Waiting for thread to finish...
res[0]
res[3]
```

Does it have anything to do with the environment? The two linux systems have same ldd version:

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
```

same GLIBC:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGT
```

and the same linux kernel version:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
```

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_join` calls `pthread_detach` after the thread has terminated.
`pthread_detach` releases all the threads resources when the thread terminates.

From the documentation of `pthread_detach`

> Attempting to detach an already detached thread results in
>          unspecified behavior.

So you have unspecified behaviour, so you can't guarantee what will happen afterwards.

At the very least, the memory pointed to by the `threadid` will be freed, leading to accessing freed memory.

In short, don't call `pthread_join` twice on the same threadid. Why would you want to?

Edit: even simpler: the man page for `pthread_join` says:

> Joining with a thread that has previously been joined results in
>          undefined behavior.